# How to pass variable in post request key?

Tags: python-3.x, string, post

I want to add a variable in key but getting error nested too deeply.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json 
for i in range(0,5):
request_payload = f'{"requests":[{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page={i}&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&facets=%5B%22brand_name%22%2C%22categories%22%2C%22sale_price%22%2C%22total_rating_average%22%2C%22express_delivery%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22categories%3AMobile%20%26%20Tablets%22%2C%22categories%3ASmartphones%22%5D%5D"},{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&hitsPerPage=1&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&clickAnalytics=false&facets=categories"}]}'
```

Here i want add variable i,

```
page={i}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying i get this which is running,

```
import requests
import json
for i in range(0,5):
    request_payload = {"requests":[{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":f"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page={i}&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&facets=%5B%22brand_name%22%2C%22categories%22%2C%22sale_price%22%2C%22total_rating_average%22%2C%22express_delivery%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22categories%3AMobile%20%26%20Tablets%22%2C%22categories%3ASmartphones%22%5D%5D"},{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&hitsPerPage=1&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&clickAnalytics=false&facets=categories"}]}
```